# DNS Issues in Hyper-V Environment

Tags: domain-name-system, hyper-v

We have just stood up a new Hyper-V host with 2 VMs in a separate subnet and physical location. When I try to promote one of the VMs to a DC, I get an error that says the following:

> The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the SRV record
>   used to locate an ADDC for domain "this.local"
>
> The error was "DNS name does not exist" error code RCODE_NAME_ERROR
>
> The query was for the SRV record for _ldap_tcp.dc_msdcs.this.local.

I can ping the DC just fine. I can RDP into all machines by IP, but not by name (since DNS is messed up.)

The subnet is in another physical location, connected by site-to-site VPN. However, we checked the tunnel and it appears to be fine.

Anyone have any fixes for this issue? Thanks.

Comment: What DNS servers are the clients in the 192.168.34.0/24 network using? Are they using your AD DNS servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot promote a DC without it being able to query the current domain by DNS.

To promote a DC it will have to find one of the current DCs in that domain, to copy the Current Active Directory-database from. It does this by using DNS-records found in the zone this.local in your case.

Comment: The new subnet is 192.168.34.0/24. The PDC is in 192.168.0.0/24, and secondary DCs reside in 9.0 and 2.0. None of the VMs in the 34.0/24 space can join the domain, regardless of whether or not they're prospective DCs. Yet, I can ping all of the DCs from 34.0/24, and I can RDP into them. Basically, on the 34.0/24 side, DNS simply does not work.

Comment: Check that the computer has a DC set as its DNS server, and verify that port 53 (TCP&UDP) have been opened. Try specific nslookup request such as nslookup this.local <IP-OF-PDC>

Comment: I ended up rebuilding the DC, using the proper DNS server as the primary (once the device was on the VPN back to the PDC), and it works now. The mistake I made was in creating the BDC and copying it over to the Hyper-V host. Thanks for your response though, as it was absolutely necessary for the BDC to be able to see another DC before being promoted.